# How to achieve "slow motion" effect in andengine on android

Tags: android, andengine

I would like to put a slow motion effect. How can i do this? I found this http://www.andengine.org/forums/post22443.html#p22443 code, but this is wrong way.
EDIT. I do not use physics, only entity modifiers

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by modifying MaxStepPhysicsEngine, look for it on the AndEngine forums. What I did was reduce the step length and increase the number of position and velocity computations accordingly.

I don't see what's wrong with the code you found, it seems to be a more elegant solution than mine.

Comment: I do not use physics engine) Thank you in any case!

Comment: Oh, you should have said that in the first place.

Comment: so what are you using? MoveModifiers? or?

Comment: I use entity modifiers and particles.

Comment: The code of the OP makes a very "choppy" slow motion effect, not at all usable in a physics scenario